# Navigate to Tab Navigator from Stack Navigator with Params

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigator, stack-navigator, tabnavigator

I'm trying to navigate to a tab navigator stack with some key params that are needed for later API calls.

```
 navigation.dispatch(
        StackActions.replace('TABNAVIGATOR', {
          userName: username,
        }),
      );
```

This is the code that i have so far, but when i try to retrieve the info using:

```
const {userName} = route.params;
```

This returns this in console log:

```
 //console.log(route);
 {"key": "SOME_KEY", "name": "NAME_OF_COMPONENT", "params": undefined}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass like this

```
 navigation.dispatch(
        StackActions.replace('TABNAVIGATOR', {
          params: {username: username},
        }),
      );

 navigation.dispatch(
        StackActions.replace('TABNAVIGATOR', {
          screen: 'TABNAVIGATORSCREEN1'
          params: {username: username},
        }),
      );
```